# I use opencv example code to capture video,I don't know why it's reversed?

Tags: opencv

This is my code.  I'm trying to capture the video and write it in to my memory.But it's wrong.

```
 import numpy as np
 import cv2

 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
 out = cv2.VideoWriter('ouput.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))

 while(1):
   ret,frame=cap.read()
  if ret==True:
     frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
     out.write(frame)
     cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):
        break
  else:
     break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the windows show the video is reversed.how could i turn it back?
thanks!

Comment: Why are u using cv2.flip

Comment: OK,it's worked,thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Dont use flip command.

```
frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
```

Check flip [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#flip).